# Discordjs createReactionCollector trigger twice

Tags: javascript, typescript, pagination, discord.js

I tried to implement a pagination using reactions on my discord bot, i started from the code of discord.js-pagination, i just made some changes to make it work and it work, except that every times the event is trigger 2 times. I logged the method to see if it was called twice but is not the case.
Here is my method :

```
    public sendPaginationMessage = async (
        message: Message,
        pages: MessageEmbed[],
        emojiList: (GuildEmoji | string)[] = ['⏪', '⏩'],
        timeout = 120000
    ) => {

        const channelId = message?.channelId

        if (!message || !channelId) {
            console.error('Channel is inaccessible.')
            return
        }

        if (!pages) {
            console.error('Pages are not given.')
            return
        }

        if (emojiList.length !== 2) {
            console.error('Need two emojis.')
            return
        }

        pages[0].footer = {text: `Page 1 / ${pages.length}`}
        const channel = await this.getChannelById(channelId) as TextChannel

        if (!channel) {
            return console.error(
                `Channel ${channelId} introuvable dans: `,
                JSON.stringify(this.discordClient.channels.cache, null, 4)
            )
        }

        const currentPage: Message = await channel.send({embeds: [pages[0]]} as MessageOptions)
        for (const emoji of emojiList) await currentPage.react(emoji)

        const filter = (reaction: MessageReaction, user: User) => {
            const emojiName = reaction.emoji.name
            return !!emojiName && message.author.id === user.id && emojiList.includes(emojiName) && !user.bot
        }

        let page = 0

        const collector = currentPage.createReactionCollector({filter, time: timeout})

        collector.on('collect', reaction => {

            reaction.users.remove(message.author)

            // Log 2 times ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
            console.log('reaction', reaction)

            const emojiName = reaction.emoji.name

            const previous = emojiName === emojiList[0]

            if (previous && page <= 0 || !previous && page + 1 >= pages.length) return

            page = previous ? --page : ++page
            pages[page].footer = {text: `Page ${page + 1} / ${pages.length}`}
            currentPage.edit({embeds: [pages[page]]} as MessageOptions)
        })

        collector.on('end', () => {
            currentPage.reactions.removeAll().catch()
        })

        return currentPage
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did the check by myself and I only get one message per reaction. I think you may have two instances of your bot running at the same time on your machine. Try to restart your computer/VPS to see if it fixes it.

Comment: Thx for your answer  I tried, i have only 1 bot running, and the method is called only once, the problem should be somewhere else. I use inversify, i'll check if i did something wrong with the dependencies injection, maybe I instanciated 2 Discord Client in my app by mistake

Comment: The problem was that I used client.login(token) 2 times. Thx you again for your help 